# Windows Phone 7 - Authenticate with Asp.net forms authentication

Tags: windows-phone-7, formsauthentication

**After clearing everything worked as expected**

I've set up a service to get asp.net forms authentication working for connection from my windows phone...

Everything is working great in the emulator ( remote connection to login and after that use the cookiecontainer to do other service requests ), but once deployed on the phone, I get login completed true correct, but any other service call doesn't work, httpcontext.currentuser.authenticated is false!

Any thoughts? And yes I'm allowing cookies on the phone and using the same cookiecontainer on all calls...

Comment: without seeing your code we'd only be guessing

Comment: I followed this: http://www.kotancode.com/2010/08/06/aspnet-authentication-wp7/

Comment: I would love to get i touch with someone to test my service... If that persons app works I could verify the code with mine...

Comment: Ok... I don't know why, but I removed all config settings and service references, set everything back and now it works............. No idea why!

Comment: it's Microsoft technology. From time to time it may work slightly... well.. unpredictable :)